# Get posts by querying taxonomy and certain terms of the taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a taxonomy called `schedule_day_taxonomy`

```
add_action( 'init', 'schedule_day_tax_func' );
function schedule_day_tax_func() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'schedule_day_taxonomy',
        'schedule',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Day',
            'query_var' => true,
            'orderby'  => 'ID', /*
        )
    );
}
```

and this `taxonomy` is assigned to a certain custom post type only.. called `schedule`

```
add_action( 'init', 'schedule_func' );

function schedule_func(){
    register_post_type('schedule', array(
        'label' => 'TV schedule',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail'),
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true, 
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'show-schedule' ),
        'labels' => array (
            'name' => 'TV schedule',
            'singular_name' => 'TV schedule',
            'menu_name' => 'TV Schedules'
        ),
    ) );
}
```

Now I want to get post by `terms` created under the taxonomy `schedule_day_taxonomy` which is assigned only for the custom post type `schedule`

I've created two terms `monday` and `tuesday`

I am trying to get all the posts if it is under the term `tuesday`. So I've tried following code:

```
<ul id="home-sche-list">
    <?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'schedule', 'posts_per_page' => 15, 'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'schedule_day_taxonomy',
                    'field' => 'tuesday',
                    'terms' => 'tuesday'
                )
            )                    
                                                );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();                           
        $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'schedule_home_page_thumb', true);   
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'schedule_taxonomy' ); 
    ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" class="wrapper-container">
            <div class="sche-thumb-con">
                <span>
                <img src="<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>" class="video-thumb hoverZoomLink" alt=""/>                                      
                    <div class="new-cat">
                    <?php 
                        foreach($terms as $term) {
                          echo $term->name;
                        } ?>
                    </div>                                              
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="sche-txt-wrapper">
                <div class="schedule-prog"><?php the_title(); ?></div>                              
                <div class="schedule-time evening">
                <?php 
                    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'schedule_time_taxonomy' ); 
                    foreach($terms as $term) {
                          echo $term->name;
                        }                                           
                ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>                              
</ul>
```

But I am getting no posts displayed. I have a post which is assigned to the term `tuesday`.

[image: DAY]

[image: Cat]

**Admin address bar**

[image: address]

What I am doing wrong? Will it affect if I assign this post to two more taxonomies (custom)?
I have two more taxonomies and those are assigned to this post.

Comment: Anyone has any idea that why I got **downvote** for this question?

Comment: Upvoted you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `field` parameter in the `tax_query` should be set to `slug` as it seems that you are passing the term slug. Any value passed to `field` except `slug` or `name` will cause the `field` parameter to default to `term_id`.

Always remember, the value passed to `field` should match the what is been passed to `terms`, so, if `terms` is term slugs, `field` should be `slug`

### EDIT

Final solution from OP taken from comments

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'schedule', 
    'posts_per_page' => 15, 
    'tax_query' => array( 
        array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'schedule_day_taxonomy', 
            'field' => 'term_id', 
            'terms' => 1278 
        ) 
    )
);
```

Comment: This works for me..
`$args = array( 'post_type' => 'schedule', 'posts_per_page' => 15, 'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'schedule_day_taxonomy',
'field' => 'id',
'terms' => 1278
 )
));`

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked. Enjoy :-)